# Es posible tener un algoritmo que sea de cifrado y a la vez función hash?

Tags: hash

Perdon por la pregunta pero me explico:

Tengo entendido que una función hash realiza operaciones uni-direccionales sobre un elemento sin posibilidad de DEVOLVER la operación a partir del resultado.

Una función de cifrado simétrica permite realizar operaciones bi - direccionales basandose en una llave, pero permitiendome encriptar y desencriptar.

Hasta aquí todo bien pero tengo la duda si es posible tener una especie de fusion entre ambas y tener así un algoritmo que cifre simetricamente pero dando como resultado un "hash" único. En otras palabras tener algo que me permita cifrar una gran cantidad de información en base a una llave y dando como resultado un código de LONGITUD FIJA tal como hace md5.

Esto es posible realmente?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uno de los principales principios de las las funciones de hashing es que no sea inversible. Esto quiere decir que una vez obtenida la firma del mensaje, no es posible obtener el mensaje a partir de ella. Por tanto, contestando a tu pregunta; no, no es posible, ya que en cualquier cifrado es necesario que el algoritmo de cifrado sea inversible, como es el caso de rsa, o cualquier cifrado simétrico.

La función de hash garantiza la integridad de los mensajes, no confidencialidad. Hay que tener bien claro esto y entender que son conceptos diferentes.

Comment: humm sospechaba que era así pero pensé que matematicamente puede existir el "santo grial" de la compresion. Comprimir un libro entero, por ejemplo, en un único hash de X longitud que al usar la clave correcta obtengamos nuevamente ese libro. En fin gracias amigo.